# поменять зону обработки поискового запроса

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Мне нужно как то получать выдачу поисковых запросов и после их обрабатывать по своиму. Поисковые запросы должны быть обработаны скажем так как если они были бы введены в пекине, как такое можно сделать? К примеру использывать nslookup etc.

Comment: Это вы делаете для yandex а?  Там же у него есть свои инструменты

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Для определения местоположения клиента по его ip адресу, вы можете воспользоваться стандартными методами PHP: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.geoip.php
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.geoip-region-by-name.php

```
<?php
$region = geoip_region_by_name('www.example.com');
if ($region)
    print_r($region);
?>
```

Или написать что-то подобное с помощью запросов к сторонним сервисам.

```
<?php
  if( $curl = curl_init() ) {
    $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://ip-whois.net/ip_geo.php?ip='.$ip);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $out = curl_exec($curl);
    $matches = array();
    $country = preg_match_all("/Страна: (.*)/i", $out, $matches);
    print_r($matches[1][1]);
    curl_close($curl);
  }
?>
```

Также на хабре подобное обсуждалось уже не раз: http://habrahabr.ru/post/138067/

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку geoip.php на  но ети методы предназначены для получения более подробной информации о юзере, мне же нужно не знать его положение, а скажем вводит на моем сайте запрос - а мой скрипт идет в 'китай' и вводит етот запрос там - результат уже интерпретию я сам

Comment: Вопрос в том как заставить скрипт сходить в китай и сделать запрос от туда

Comment: Вы можете определить регион пользователя и с помощью условных операторов направить клиент или отправить его запрос на нужный вам сервер.

Comment: спасибо за ссылки, но вопрос не стоит в том чтобы определить от куда юзер, Вопрос в том чтобы его запрос прогнать через скажем гугл китая и вернуть мне...  Спасибо

Comment: Насколько я понял, вы хотите отправлять запросы пользователя на разные сервера в зависимости от его гео положения?

Comment: гео положение юзера сдесь роли никакой не играет и мне его не нужно знать и узнавать. Если упростить - как мне отправить на гугл китая запрос 'buy apple 6' -  и получить те ответы который выдаст поисковик китая?